# How to animate multiple growing circles in pixi.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pixi.js

Ive been studying code and learning about algorithms and different methods and concepts. I'm currently working on circle packing and trying to get past the first  phase. Im relatively new to javascript and have only dealt with Java and minimal c++.

I have written a `class` called `CircleShape` and I am initializing that `class` into an array, which allows me to draw multiple circles to the screen with code like so:

```
var renderer;
var graphics;

var widthOfScreen = 800;
var heightOfScreen = 400;

var circles = [];

function initRenderer() {

    console.log("initializing renderer 2..");

    renderer = new PIXI.Application(widthOfScreen, heightOfScreen, { antialias: true });
    document.getElementById("pixidisplay-1").appendChild(renderer.view);

    graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        circles[i] = new CircleShape(Math.floor((Math.random() * widthOfScreen) + 1), Math.floor((Math.random() * heightOfScreen) + 1), Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1));
    }       
}

function draw() {
    console.log("drawing 2..");

    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        circles[i].drawCircleShape();
    }    
}

function CircleShape(_x, _y, _s) {

    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.s = _s;

    var str = '#1C3144', num = parseInt(str.substring(1), 16);

    this.drawCircleShape = function drawCircleShape() {

    graphics.lineStyle(0);
    graphics.beginFill(num, 1);
    graphics.drawCircle(this.x, this.y,this.s);
    graphics.endFill();

    renderer.stage.addChild(graphics);

    }
}

initRenderer();
draw();
```

In previous experiements, I've managed to make a single circle grow in its size by using:

```
app.ticker.add(function(delta) {
  circle.scale.set(size);
  size = size + 0.1 * delta;
});
```

And this would be executed after the drawing of the circle itself, circle being a variable with a `PIXI.Graphics()` assigned to it.

Initially I had the `circle.drawCircle(0,0,this.s)` and had tried incrementing the `s` variable by doing so in side the `ticker.add(function(delta)`. Because I didn't have any success, I decided to use `circle.scale.set(s)` instead. I'm still unsure which is the best method. Im unsure if its better to have the `PIXI.Graphics` initialization outside the Circle `class` or inside it. (I would assume inside the class, but with javascript I really don't know)

Basically the goal for me is to take the class and array method, drawing circles to the screen in random positions, either once, or continuously, with the circle growing over time, and being able to adjust the amount the circle grows.

Eventually I will use some kind of conditionals to make a the circle stop growing as it touches another circle or the edge of the canvas.

Any help would be much appreciated. Winston

I will be posting some examples of where I'm up to in a moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few more attempt I've managed to reach my objective and heres the code which I written if anyone would like to take a look. Still a work in progress.

[code here](https://github.com/WinstonItiDev/Javascript_Experiments)

:)